# What is this white stuff inside this circuit board?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor

I'm having problem getting any output from this universal adapter for my older laptop, so I opened it up to see this rubber-like white substance inside, on top of the big 68uF 400V capacitor.[image: Laptop DC adapter]

A closeup:
[image: closeup]

If it is glue, why would they use it? It fits well without it, with the leads of that capacitor bent as they are.

Comment: You gotta love all the safety and protection components that clearly *could* be installed on that board, but have been replaced with wire jumpers or left out entirely. Aaaahhh, quality Chinese products!

Comment: I like to think that there is actually only one, giant circuit board design in China that they break off and use for every electronic component in the world.

Comment: Another application is for magnetics to stop vibrating. A common thing is after years they dry out and you hear them making annoying sounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of times you'll use glue/epoxy to protect against a mechanical shock (i.e. dropping it). Put it on the at-risk items, like the biggest capacitor, and you have more anchor points with less stress on the solder joints.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this is a silicone elastomer which as mentioned helps to keep large components in place or closely spaced components from touching.